# How to create a Matrix table on SQL from another table

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table with the following columns.

```
    ------------------------------------- 
     Column1 | Column2 | TotalCount
    --------------------------------------
         1         1         40
         1         2         50
         2         1         10
         2         2         60
```

Also, I have another table that is related to Column1 where 1 is X and 2 is Y and same for Column2 where 1 is A and 2 is B

I am trying to come up with a SQL statement that basically gives me some view like...

```
       --------------------
        ColumnName | A | B
       --------------------
           X        40   50
           Y        10   60
```

Any idea how can I achieve that? I've been trying to pivot the data with no luck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Full working example:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [Column1] TINYINT
   ,[Column2] TINYINT
   ,[TotalCount] TINYINT
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([Column1], [Column2], [TotalCount])
VALUES (1, 1, 40)
      ,(1, 2, 50)
      ,(2, 1, 10)
      ,(2, 2, 60);

SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT IIF([Column1] = 1, 'X', 'Y') AS [ColumnName]
          ,IIF([Column2] = 1, 'A', 'B') AS [Column2]
          ,[TotalCount]
    FROM  @DataSource
) DS
PIVOT 
(
    MAX([TotalCount]) FOR [Column2] IN ([A], [B])
) PVT;
```

[image]

Comment: Wow... that looks awesome! What if the number of values you have in Column1 and Column2 are unknown until you run the query? Could be possible to do something similar?

Comment: @user3587624 In order to make the `PIVOT` you need to know the values of `[Column2]` - `[Column1]` is not important as we are doing grouping over it (it could be any value).

Comment: So.. .does it mean then that I can have 5000 elements in Column1 and Column2 that I don't need to know their values?

Comment: In order to use the `PIVOT` clause you should now the values on which you are doing it. For example, in the statement above we knew that we had values `A` and `B` and these values become columns headers.

Comment: I see.. then I can't use PIVOT as I don't know the values of which I am pivoting around as these values can be incremented/decremented from time to time. Is there any other alternative then?

Comment: You can create the so called `dynamic PIVOT` - there are a lot of examples how to do it. Basically, you are creating a `dynamic T-SQL` statement which is then executed via `sp_executesql` procedure or `EXECUTE` command.

Comment: @user3587624 Could you post additional sample data and update the expected result? Some users might have a solution for your dynamic pivot.

Answer (score 1):

Using conditional aggregation:

```
WITH tbl AS(
    SELECT * FROM ( VALUES
        (1, 1, 40), (1, 2, 50),
        (2, 1, 10), (2, 2, 60)
    )t(Column1, Column2, TotalCount) 
)
SELECT
    ColumnName = CASE WHEN Column1 = 1 THEN 'X' ELSE 'Y' END,
    A = MAX(CASE WHEN Column2 = 1 THEN TotalCount END),
    B = MAX(CASE WHEN Column2 = 2 THEN TotalCount END)
FROM tbl
GROUP BY Column1
```

RESULT:

```
ColumnName A           B
---------- ----------- -----------
X          40          50
Y          10          60
```